# Link facebook and google with windows Java program

Tags: java, facebook

I am trying to create application for windows.
Which will show Facebook account events,
also want to link Gmail and Google calendar events.

This is only plans, that's why there is no code.

I would like to ask for any suggestion, tips, reading material in general,
for any ideas how to make this, and what I should use additionally.

P.S. working with JAVA.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Google is pretty simple, just use google API to connect to the service and retrieve the data you need. Google has pretty damn good APi documentation so it's not too difficult. On other hand, I'm not sure how you would implement the facebook one, i assume they also have an API but it might be a little more difficult then google.

Answer (score 0):

Both Facebook and Google calendar provide private ics -links you can use to get the events.

There seems to be a project called "iCal4j" (http://build.mnode.org/projects/ical4j/) you could use. It's a Java library for reading and writing iCalendar files.